# NodeJS response.on('data') doesn't fire when I add hook to request emit

Tags: node.js, eventemitter, node-https

I make https request with Node's `https.request()` and listen to response `'data'` event:

```
const req = https.request('https://stackoverflow.com/', res => {
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('data');
    })
});

req.end();
```

I works fine. I get `'data'` outputs in console.

However, when I add hook to reqest's emit (for debug purposes) as this:

```
const req = https.request('https://stackoverflow.com/', res => {
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('data');
    })
});
const original_emit = req.emit;
req.emit = function(event_name) {
    console.log('reqest event: ' + event_name);
    original_emit.apply(req, arguments);
};

req.end();
```

I don't get `'data'` output anymore. 
Cannot find reason for that.

Node version: 8.11.3

Comment: I think you need to monkeypatch the request prototype before calling `request`.  However, why monkeypatch at all?  Why not attach 2 listeners?

Comment: @zero298 Sorry, don't understand your solution. Buy anyway, I'm wondering why these weird things happen with my solution.